# Stack using two queues not displaying output

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack

I have written code for stack using two queues but the code is not giving output when i try to push and pop the  value from the stack.
Here is the complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


struct Queue{
    int front;
    int rear;
    int capacity;
    int *arr;
};

int isFull(Queue *q){
    return ((q->rear+1)%q->capacity == q->front);
}

int isEmpty(Queue *q){


    return (q->front==-1);
}

void push(Queue *q,int data){
    if(!isFull(q)){

        //chk if the first element is going to be inserted

        if(isEmpty(q)){
            q->front=0;
        }


        q->rear=(q->rear+1)%q->capacity;

        q->arr[q->rear]=data;

    }
}

int removeFront(Queue *q){
    if(!isEmpty(q)){

        int result=q->arr[q->front];
        if(q->front==q->rear){
            q->front=q->rear=-1;

        }

        else{
            //increase the front of the queue
            q->front=(q->front+1)%q->capacity;
        }

        return result;

    }


    return -1;
}



int pop(Queue *q1,Queue *q2){
    //move all the items fro the queue 1 to queue 2
    while (!isEmpty(q1))
    {
        push(q2,removeFront(q1));
    }
    //store and return the element from the queue 2
    int res=removeFront(q2);


    while (!isEmpty(q2)) {
        push(q1, removeFront(q2));
    }


    return res;  //return the popped itm


    

}

int main(){

    //initialization

    Queue *q1=new Queue;
    Queue *q2=new Queue;
    q1->front=q2->rear=-1;
    q1->capacity=q2->capacity=10;
    q1->arr=(int *)malloc(q1->capacity*sizeof(int));
    q2->arr=(int *)malloc(q2->capacity*sizeof(int));
```

When I push the item in the stack and try to print the popped result. it doesn,t display any output.

```
    push(q1,10);
    push(q1,20);
    push(q1,30);

    cout<<pop(q1,q2);



//free the allocated memory
    delete[] q1->arr;
    delete[] q2->arr;
    delete q1;
    delete q2;



    return 0;
}
```

Checked the code but not able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not properly initialised your queues:

```
q1->front=q2->rear=-1;
```

This leaves `q1-rear` and `q2->front` uninitialised, and so you get undefined behaviour. As `q2->front` is likely not equal to -1, the last `while` loop in `pop` will never finish: the `removeFront` call will never reach a point where `front` becomes equal to `rear` because `front` is non-negative by the `%` operator, and `rear` is -1.

The solution is to properly initialise all four members to -1:

```
q1->front=q1->rear=-1;
q2->front=q2->rear=-1;
```

### Remark

Not your question, but this is not how you program in C++.

- You should not need to call `malloc`. Don't define `arr` as a pointer, but as a vector.
- Define `Queue` as a class with `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods. Your `main` function should not have to initialise the members of its queues. This should be done by the `Queue` constructor.
- Define also a class `Stack` with `push` and `pop` methods

Comment: Thanks ! I am a student and I have shifted from C.